# inserting uploads into subdomain

Tags: customization

I have my wordpress blog in the root of my website (example.org) and would like to store uploaded files in a subdomain depending on type of file, for example I currently have static.example.org/images, static.example.org/video and static.example.org/audio and was trying to find a way to put uploaded files in the subdomain through the Wordpress Interface.

I've found a plugin which is quite dynamic in storing files, but it won't pass to subdomians, can anybody help or suggest anything?

Comment: just grab the extension of the file and then place it in the physical path + something like "domains" + extension.YOURBLOG ?

Comment: Which plugin were/are you using? How was your solution in the end?

Comment: In the end, I was happy to store my files in a single subfolder, I didn't bother about seperating them up into music/video/images. I did this by using the method provided by @Luis in the answer above (see image:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/9jaez.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the upload path by referring to following tutorial, then use the plugin again.

http://7php.com/how-to-change-the-path-of-uploading-file-in-wordpress-2-8-x-2-9-x-without-touching-the-code-configurations/